# share objects between nodejs modules using module.exports

Tags: node.js, express, module, socket.io

Here how I have structured my code

**Main .js**

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var  app = express();
var  io = require('socket.io')(http.createServer(app));

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

module.exports.io = io; // because I wont to access this object from Home.js module
```

**Index.js**

```
var express = require('express')
, router = express.Router();
router.use('/home', require('./home'))
module.exports = router
```

**Home.js**

```
var express = require('express')
, router = express.Router();

io = require('../main').io;
router.get('/', function(req, res,next) {
res.send("response from home controller"+ io );
})
```

Now here's the issue 
When I try to access 
    http://localhost:3000/home
, I get following response 
"response from home controller undefined" ( undefined  for object io)

Guys can you highlight where exactly I'm messing it wrong

Comment: var io = require('../main').io; I guess you need to define the io (not so sure though)

Comment: sounds like you need a better understanding of some basics: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Comment: @dave, I went through the link, did not find anything wrong, would appreciate if you could highlight the error

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have not defined your variable in Home.js

Change this `io = require('../main').io;` to `var io = require('../main').io;` in Home.js

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

**Home.js**

```
var express = require('express');
, router = express.Router();

var io = require('../main');
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("response from home controller "+ io );
});
```

I have been desperately trying to find a more proper solution for the problem to make io available in different files, but till now I just found the one I mentioned here.